# Maximum difference in an array

Tags: java, arrays

For this array `{2,6,1,5,10,7}` following code will return 10-1=9.Please explain how it works and how did this logic found the minimum value 1 in that array.

```
void method(int[] ar,int n) {
    int max =ar[1]-ar[0];
    int i,j;
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(ar[j]-ar[i]>max)
                max=ar[j]-ar[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

Comment: Why not just sort and subtract last index value - first index value?

Comment: It works (inefficiently) by looking at every combination of two values, calculating their difference, and seeing if it's higher than the previous winner. For instance, it'll look at 6-2, 1-2, 5-2,...

Comment: If you are asking why this O(n^2) algorithm fails, it is because you omitted abs() and are skipping half of the comparisons.

Comment: since you are looking for feedback on the code, perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for that.

Comment: This algorithm does not find the minimum or maximum elements. It looks at all possible differences (i.e. inefficient, O(n^2)) and finds the maximum difference.

Comment: Plus you have to do the calculation in `long` to avoid overflow (unless these `int` are constrained to be positive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic makes an assumption that the maximum difference in the array is between the first two numbers.

Max variable is used to save the maximum difference

```
max = arr[1] - arr[0] //assumption made that the the first two integers give the max difference
```

Now we create a nested loop so that difference of a number is calculated with all other values in the array.

But we don't need to check the values that already have been computed to save our time. Since we only need the difference I would like to point out taht we take the difference as always positive. Hence we only take care of the values ahead as

`abs(arr[0] - arr[1]) = abs(arr[1] - arr[0])`

where abs represents the absolute value.

Now while comparing the difference of the one value with other values whenever the algorithm finds any difference that is greater than the maximum alue it updates the value of max.

So after exiting the loop we have the max difference in the array values.

PS: A better approach would be to sort the array and then subtract the index and the last value

PPS: If you want better understanding of this loop you can also look into Selection Sort

Answer (score 3):

You just need to find max number and min number within one loop :

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE , min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++){
    max = Math.max(arr[i], max);
    min = Math.min(arr[i], min);
}

System.out.println(max - min);
```

Comment: I think, Math.max and Math.min methods internally uses loop to find the min and max value ..

Comment: @SMANSARI  just 2 values , loop to find ?

Comment: Math.max() method internally uses for loop or some looping method. so It is not single loop to find the solution I think.

Comment: @SMANSARI Does it?get max of 2 uses loop？

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] a = { 2, 6, 1, 5, 10, 7 };
            Arrays.sort(a);
            System.out.println(a[a.length - 1] - a[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also not terribly efficient. You can just get both max and min in a single pass over the array.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is getting '9' as answer is because the max difference that's being counted is `10-1=9`.

Consider the loop when `i=2` and `j=4`

The max difference that's counted is
=> `max = ar[j] - ar[i];`
=> `max = 10 - 1;`
=> `max = 9`

---

**EDIT**

But of course, a more optimal approach would be to sort the array and find the difference between first and last element.

```
Arrays.sort(ar);
System.out.println(ar[ar.length-1] - ar[0]);
```

**Output**

```
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Code complexity is very high in your program.

There is always better way of doing it

mine is

```
    int[] numArray = {2,6,1,5,10,7};
    int max = numArray[0];
    int min = numArray[0];
    for( int i : numArray){ 
      if( max < i )
        max = i;
      if( min > i )
        min = i;
    }
System.out.println("Maximum Difference of an Array is "+(max - min ));
```

Comment: Understood. I posted this since the question was not clear to me

Comment: I edited the code. Now it works fine than the posted one

Comment: Why have you answered the question twice?

Comment: didn't notice. now not able to delete

Answer (score 0):

This solution is used for not sorted array with negative numbers

```
public int computeDifference() {
    int min_ele = arr[0];
    int max_ele = arr[0];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min_ele)
            min_ele = arr[i];
        if (arr[i]>max_ele)
            max_ele = arr[i];
    }
    return Math.abs(max_ele - min_ele);
}
```